# Adaptive Cards - Is it possible to enforce that the user typed something in Input Text Field before Action.Submit is allowed

Tags: adaptive-cards

I'm trying to use adaptive cards on MS Teams to capture some user input text before they click on submit. One of the things I would like to have is that I want the user to input some non-empty string before the Action.Submit is allowed to go through.

Is that an existing support feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This feature, called Input Validation, is part of the upcoming v1.3 release, which will be available in Teams in the next few months. Here is a same that uses the "required" property to indicate something must be entered.

{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.3",
"body": [
{
"type": "Input.Text",
"id": "name",
"placeholder": "First, last",
"label": "Please enter your name",
"isRequired": true,
"errorMessage": "Name is required"
}
],
"actions": [
{
"type": "Action.Submit",
"title": "Save"
}
]
}

You can learn about it here. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/adaptive-cards-community-call-july-2020/

Comment: Hey. It seems this is not available in Teams yet. Any news?